# PowerShell - Get-LocalUser in Foreach statement

Tags: powershell

Thank you all in advance.... I'm trying to get a list of users per server... trying to figure out why its listing all the users from all the servers together & hope to properly separate it...

right now it shows users of server2 under server3...

see my output below the code...

Thank you!

```
function checkadmin {
    clear
    $userName = 'McAdmin'
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'xxxx' -AsPlainText -Force
    $group = 'Administrators'
    $servers = ('dev12','43dev','mt-lw-apps03')


    foreach($server in $servers) {

    Write-Host $server -ForegroundColor blue -BackgroundColor White


    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ArgumentList $userName, $password, $group, $test -ScriptBlock {



       if (!(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name  Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts)){  
                Write-Host "Module not Installed on" $args[3]
                Write-Host "-----------------------------------"
                }



       else {

            if(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name  Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts){
                Write-Host "WMI Module exists"
                Write-Host "Listing Users:"
                Write-Host "-----------------------------------"
                Get-LocalUser
                Write-Host "-----------------------------------"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
checkadmin
```

[image]

Comment: But your listing already contains the computername - what's the issue?

Comment: I need the first 4 users to be listed under 43dev section, not together with mt-lw-apps03...

Comment: btw: Get-Command only works locally, in my script                                               
   if (!(Get-Command -Name Get-LocalUser))  
                
       *** it says "'Get-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Comment: Use `Get-Command Get-LocalUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to suppress the error.